# Android Bluetooth LE and Classic Bluetooth API

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I am writing an App to be able to connect to Bluetooth LE devices and old classic Bluetooth devices.
In Android OS 4.3, different API is used for LE and classic.

How can I auto-detect to know that the devices that I connected to are Bluetooth LE devices or classic Bluetooth devices so that I can choose the correct API to connect?

Answer (score 2):

You have probably to scan the devices twice, for BLE devices use: BluetoothAdapter.startLeScan, for classic Bluetooth devices use: BluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery.

Comment: I can paired the devices first and use BluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices() to get the devices list to choose from. Get the correct device name and start the appropriate services (BLE or classic)